# Magento 2 - Product Customizable Options is not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, magento2.3, customizable-options

i create a product with Customizable Options but sometimes at frontend, the place which custom options should have appeared is now nothing
[image]

I'm not sure why it happen, but when i resaving the product seems to solve that.
Any idea what's the cause? How to prevent that? How to fix that for all products without resaving them all?

Comment: You can refer this issue in Github:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10469

Comment: hi @KirtiNariya i see this, but It has not been resolved yet in your link

Answer (score 4):

After create or update product attribute programmatically  (like tier price , etc..) by mistake product has_option set with false value.

check in "catalog_product_entity" table.

```
select entity_id, has_options, sku from `catalog_product_entity` where  sku = {sky of yourproduct}
```

So update it if has_options value is zero or null.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` set has_options =1 where  sku = {sky of yourproduct}
```

As describe @Gulshan. find out and update product which has_options column value are false.

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE entity_id in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_option`) and has_options = 0;
```

And update it with update query. Before update keep backup for table "catalog_product_entity" table.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` set has_options =1 where entity_id in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_option`) and has_options = 0 ;
```

Refresh cache and check product detail page.

Comment: Thanks sumit, I have got same issue after migrate my site.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the issue.

After doing some investigation I found that has_options column has 0 but product have at least one option associated in the product options table.

I didn't find a scenario to reproduce but it seems the product options were imported by any third party extension or migrated from an older version of Magento.

Re-saving product resolves the issue because there is a check at before product save that updates has_options value to 1.

So, I prepared below query to find all such products and managed to save all the resulted products.

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE entity_id in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_option`) and has_options = 0
```

I hope this may help someone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

its because of $product->save()

when you save product with orm, its setting has_options to 0.
Shortly its a magento bug.
To fix that issue in db level, you can execute the query below.

```
update catalog_product_entity t1 
inner join catalog_product_option t2 on t2.product_id = t1.entity_id
set t1.has_options = 1
where t1.has_options = 0 and t1.type_id = 'simple';
update catalog_product_entity t1
inner join catalog_product_option t2 on t2.product_id = t1.entity_id and t2.is_require = 1
set t1.required_options = 1
where t1.required_options = 0
and t1.type_id = 'simple';
```